# Image in JApplet

Tags: java, eclipse, image, null, japplet

I am trying to display an image in a JApplet.  I am trying to load an image, then draw it.  However, I keep getting the following error when I try to initialize my BufferedImage red:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1362)
    at Pathfinder.init(Pathfinder.java:15)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:425)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

It was originally in a resources folder, but I was getting the same error.  I tried it in a `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() { ...`, but it still did not work.  Any ideas what is wrong?  My program is as follows:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Pathfinder extends Applet {
    private BufferedImage red;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            red = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("red.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(red, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

red.png exists in the uppermost level of my project.

Comment: Try using red = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("/red.png")); instead. getClass().getResource(...) uses a relative path based on the classes package location...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Thanks, but same result. :(

Comment: Show the structure of the Jar.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it's not in a JAR. I'm just pressing play in eclipse.

Comment: Then you need to figure out how Eclipse puts things on the run-time class-path of the app.  Given your newbieness, why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson im japplet newb. Not Java newb. I'm going applet cuz i have a swing app I wanna put it on my website. But I may end up just using that other converter thing at this point.

Comment: *"Not Java newb."*  I'd expect someone who is not a newbie to understand the run-time class-path and how to configure it for their IDE.  In fact, I'd expect them to have that sorted before they attempt *any form* of GUI let alone an applet, which is quite an advanced form (from the POV of difficulty of development). *"i have a swing app I wanna put it on my website."*  A better thing to do is just (install and) launch the desktop app. from a link using **[Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)**.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank you for your feedback. I will discontinue Java GUI development until I have a better understanding of Java.